# Schema.org contactType validation issue: "The value provided for office must be a valid contact type"

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

Below is a snippet from my JSON-LD for a site I'm working on.

I cannot get it to validate though as it says that there "The value provided for office must be a valid contact type." How do I make this a valid contact type? I can't find any documentation on this.

```
<script type='application/ld+json'>
{
  "@context": "http://www.schema.org",
  "@type": "EntertainmentBusiness",
  "contactPoint": {
     "@type": "ContactPoint",
     "contactType": "office",
     "telephone": "+44 (0)1234 567890"
   }   
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The [`contactType`](http://schema.org/contactType) property expects text and doesn’t recommend any values, so using "office" is perfectly fine.

But if you want to get Google’s [Corporate Contacts](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/corporate-contacts) feature, you have to provide a value that Google recognizes:

> "customer support", "technical support", "billing support", "bill payment", "sales", "reservations", "credit card support", "emergency", "baggage tracking", "roadside assistance", "package tracking"

(**Edit:** They seem to have updated their documentation, and now they no longer list "customer support", but "customer service" instead.)

As you can see, "office" is not among them.

If you don’t care for this Google search result feature, you can keep it like that.

Comment: That's perfect, thanks for your help.  That all validated fine now.

Comment: What is the source of this documentation information? @unor

Comment: @FelipeValdes: Do you mean the list of contact type value that Google recognizes? It’s listed on Google’s Corporate Contacts documentation (which I linked).